# Como escrever o teste JUnit com o Spring Autowire?

Tags: spring, junit, injeção-de-dependência

Atualmente estou configurando um projeto Dynamic Web para executar testes unitários, porém esse projeto está usando injeções de dependências pelo Spring FrameWorks, é importante mencionar que a versão do spring que existe na minha aplicação é do 3.0.4, e não existe chances de atualizar a versão no meu projeto porque os impactos serial muito grandes.

Na versão atual do spring, as configurações para Junit seria feito através de anotações, porém pela documentação da versão 3.0.4 eram feitas com configuração de arquvios **XML**.

**É importante explicar o contexto para antes eu solicitar a ajuda.**

Para configurar os testes unitários do Junit só bastaria colocar um classe e configurar ela como sendo um componente do Spring numa pasta especifica do projeto onde estão localizados os pacotes do Model, Controller e os Services, e ela ficaria dessa forma;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E na classe onde seriam executado os testes colocar incluir as anotações dessa forma;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essas configurações seriam importantes para o **@Autowired** pudesse funcionar no projeto, caso contrário as configurações não fossem feitas dessa forma o **@Autowired** não iria ser injetado e no ato de executar o teste iria dar **NullPointerException**.

Na versão 3.0.4 as configurações são feitas de forma diferente, só relembrando que a versão do meu projeto é do 3.0.4.

Dar uma olhada na minha classe de testes;

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext.xml" })
public class IndicioDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    private IndicioDAO indicioDAO;

    @Test
    public void findByIdIndicio() {

        TipoIndicioEntity tipoIndicio = new TipoIndicioEntity();
        tipoIndicio.setCodigo(1);

        NaturezaIndicioEntity naturezaIndicio = new NaturezaIndicioEntity();
        naturezaIndicio.setCodigo(1);

        SituacaoIndicioEntity situacaoIndicio = new SituacaoIndicioEntity();
        situacaoIndicio.setCodigo(1);

        IndicioEntity indicio = new IndicioEntity();
        indicio.setCodigo(1);
        indicio.setTipoIndicio(tipoIndicio);
        indicio.setCodigoNaturezaIndicio(naturezaIndicio.getCodigo());
        indicio.setSituacaoAtual(situacaoIndicio);

        IndicioEntity result = indicioDAO.getPorId(indicio.getCodigo());

        assertThat(result, notNullValue());

    }
```

Nas anotações são tentando mapear o arquivo XML do projeto, no nosso contexto é o **applicationContext.xml**, como mostra no trecho de código abaixo;

> @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext.xml" })

Porém ela tem que está mapeada da forma correta, ao tentar executar um teste ele deu essa mensagem de erro abaixo;

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:333)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceControle': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 37 more
```

Isso está acontecendo porque o arquivo **applicationContext.xml** está mapeada de forma incorreta;

Eu já tentei dessas formas;

> @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/../applicationContext.xml" })

**Preciso somente saber a forma correta de mapear o arquivo!**

Veja onde ele está localizado o meu arquivo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei utilizar esse exemplo;

[Spring @ContextConfiguration como colocar o local correto para o xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377699/spring-contextconfiguration-how-to-put-the-right-location-for-the-xml)

E adaptei dessa forma;

> @ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:applicationContext.xml",
>   "file:resources/struts.xml", "file:resources/tiles.xml"
>
> })

Porém sem sucesso;

O problema da minha aplicação é EU conseguir passar  o contexto das configurações do seu servidor!

Comment: Pelo erro, parece que o arquivo está sendo encontrado corretamente mas tem algum problema na configuração do XML. Caso contrário, você receberia um erro que o arquivo não foi encontrado, como este: `class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`